# Where are *.stackdump files created by programs running under Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, stack-dump

I run an autotest system that uses some external tools to conduct the testing. If one of them crashes - although the tool itself is not what I'm testing - I'd like to save the `foo.exe.stackdump` file that is created. However, I have been unable to find a clear answer as to where this file is created. My assumption was that it would be in the working directory (but I can't verify that because the directory is automatically purged between tests) and I haven't been able to find a clear answer online.
I'm using Cygwin 1.7.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, they're created in the working directory.

That said, have you tried disabling the automatic purging and just seeing what happens? That'll give you an immediate and verifiable result specific to your situation.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the crash (this runs all day, and I've only seen it happen once over many weeks), and disabling it is unfortunately not an option. We do have tests for the tool itself as well, so a best-effort attempt here might be sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: @Ffejery: Possibly add something in your test that checks for the existence of a `*.stackdump` file, and halts all testing if it's there?